# Can solids behave like liquids?

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, collision, states-of-matter

Basically, the more I look at things the more it seems like there's entirely no difference between a liquid and gas, it all just depends on the relative density of what's around it. This being said, can this be extended to solids? If you had a solid which was a great deal denser than the ground around it, we'll call it a super rock, would it sink through the ground, making waves, like if you dropped an ordinary rock into a pond? By that standards do we effectively float on the floor?

Comment: I don't think your intuition is so accurate...surely there are situations in which the distinction between solid and liquid is not so clear. As an example, you may not know that glass is sometimes considered a liquid (in any case, it has a particular structure that differs from the standard one of a solid).

Comment: It's easily seen that denser solids *do not* sink into less dense solids. Just take any two solid objects in your vicinity with differing density and put them on top of each other. They don't sink/mix, do they?

Comment: "...there's entirely no difference between a liquid and gas, it all just depends on the relative density of what's around it."

No, the difference depends on the timescale involved.  At a short enough timescale nothing flows; at a long enough timescale, many more things flow.

Answer (score 3):

Liquids and gases are both *fluids*, meaning they flow(duh) and will take the shape of their container. Gases will expand to fill the container, while liquids will not.

Solids are not fluids and do not conform to their container's shape.  Yes, I know you can squeeze things to fit (e.g. a sponge), but only at the cost of distorting the structure and storing potential energy in the stressed structure.

Don't confuse, say, the separation of sand from pebbles from rocks in a shaker with dense solids falling thru less dense solids.  This has more to do with statistical motion and packing theory.   The only way through a solid ie either by breaking it (which has nothing to do with density) or by forcing a deformation or local melting (see experiments with a rock on top of a block of ice for a classic example).